# WCF Webhook Service, How to convert POST message stream into useful data?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

Good evening, I am attempting to build a WCF service that will listen for a webhook call from a website, in my case www.formstack.com. I am able to get the WCF service working and accepting data but the stream and/or message format is being returned as a long URL formatted text string instead of XML. I have looked in to formstack and it does not have any other way to format the message.

This is what is being returned.  I ultimately need this into a format that I can then submit it to a database.

> FormID=1730225&UniqueID=166942101&Ticket+Number=&System+Number=&Customer+Number=&Customer+Name=&Your+Name=Brad+Swindell&Email=&Score=10+-+Very+Likely&Additional+Feedback=This+is+%22A+Test%22%2C+that+has+%3D+and+%26+symbol%27s+in+it.&Would+you+like+this+survey+to+be+anonymous%3F=No&Tech=&Id=

I could try to parse the text by & and = and then replace the +. but I would have to trap every other symbol. Is there a better way to approach this issue?

This is my current code:

```
Public Function PostSampleMethod(data As Stream) As String Implements IMyService.PostSampleMethod
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
    Dim xmlString As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("C:\log.txt")
        Log(xmlString, w)
    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Formstack Webhook API - https://www.formstack.com/developers/webhooks

I was wondering if VB.Net has a library that can handle this process and decode/parse it, or I am going about getting the data from the POST the wrong way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys for the help.

Brad Swindell

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would submit the accepted solution.  The HttpUtility class does the work of parsing the POST data in to a NameValueCollection that can then be retrieved individually.

```
Public Function PostSampleMethod(data As Stream) As String Implements IMyService.PostSampleMethod
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
    Dim xmlString As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Dim httpResponse As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(xmlString)

    For i As Integer = 0 To httpResponse.Count - 1  
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", {httpResponse.Keys(i), httpResponse.Item(i)})
    Next 

    Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("C:\log.txt")
        Log(httpResponse.Get("FormID"), w)
        Log(httpResponse.Get("UniqueID"), w)
        Log(httpResponse.Get("HandshakeKey"), w)
    End Using

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Brad Swindell